# How handle large number of images in gallery node Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, media, files

I have some gallery nodes with a large number of images (100+), the upload with [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) integration module works fine, but after save the node and edit it again the node edit form loads 20+ seconds! How can I reduce the loading time of the form? Somebody have any suggestion for this problem? [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) of Fields possible? Pagination? Some Module?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested what actually takes so long? SQL query? File download to user? Something else? Withuot knowing the reason, we can't guess solution.

Comment: Devel protocol showed me a huge number of sql queries so i tried entitycache module in combination with memcache! Tests: Deactivated Entity Cache Executed 2361 queries in 16415.45 ms.  Activated Entity Cache  Executed 412 queries in 627.84 ms. Source Devel! What do you think about this solution?

Comment: With Drupal you always get a huge number of queries. San you see if they actually take a lot of time? I would try memcached if I suspected query-related speed problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the intended site behaviour, or interface, for your galleries.  However, I would restructure the site.  Have you looked at each gallery "entry" being a node with 1 picture field and 1 taxonomy term reference?  The terms would then be your "galleries", you could use views to build the pages any way you want, even lazy load.  You could add sorting, and since you would not have 100+ field entries on any one entity, loading the entity into a variable for the various page build tasks would be far faster.  Gallery nodes work fine if they have less than 30 entries, but it sounds like your data management could use some revision.